# Are Blender questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I am new to Game Development and I am studying game programming in India. I learn game designing via YouTube and other online sources. Where can I ask Blender related questions?

Comment: Historically, we took a lot of Blender questions related to modeling for games as well (as this site predates the Blender SE), but now that Blender SE exists, most questions involving Blender are better suited there.

Answer (score 7):

If your looking for help on modelling in Blender then head over to Blender Stack Exchange:

http://blender.stackexchange.com

If you want to ask people on things like importing your blender models then feel free to post anywhere here. But if it's a question about being in the Blender editor it's self then ask them at Blender Stack Exchange.