# Should we consider Blender related questions off-topic when they're not about game development?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

A [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152974/using-jpegs-as-backgrounds) was recently bumped by Community. This question is about [blender](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender), but not in the context of game development.

We typically allow Blender questions, but since StackExchange has a site just about it, should we have the rule that if the question is not about game development, we close the question and/or ask for migration?

FWIW, we have [this meta question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/are-blender-questions-on-topic-here), that says that this kind of question *should* be asked on blender.se, and the tag itself suggests this too. I'm asking if we should formally consider those off-topic. This would allow mods to close them on sight, and non-mods to refer to something when voting to close.

Comment: Worth revisiting. The linked meta question lacks an accepted answer & looking at the profile data, it looks like OP raised the issue & then left.

Comment: Yes, the apparent consensus is that they _should_ be asked on [blender.se], but _should_ is not mandatory. There is this pandemic now, our governments tell us that we _should not_ travel abroad, but since it's not _forbidden_ people do it anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Officially off-topic, refer them to BSE in my opinion.

Comment: +1, I think this is in line with our generic programming questions policy.

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason not to off-topic Blender questions that aren't about game dev. Even in the grey area of "a game dev would give better answers to my question", the question would need to be framed in a way that would make it game dev related. Not game dev related means not on-topic.